# Unramified map between local noetherian rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $A \subseteq B$ a finite type inclusion of two regular local noetherian rings. Let's call $\mathfrak{m}, \mathfrak{n}$ the maximal ideals of $A,B$ respectively. Let's suppose that $\mathfrak{m}B=\mathfrak{n}$ and $\dfrac{A}{\mathfrak{m}} \cong \dfrac{B}{\mathfrak{n}}$.

With this condition, I've got that the map is unramified and so that $\Omega_{B/A}=0$. Now, I've got a doubt: given that, let's call $F,K$ the fraction fields respectively of $A,B$, one should get $\Omega_{K/F}=0$ which in general  is not true.

What am I missing??

Comment: It's true if $K/F$ is separable and to have unramifiedness at the generic point of $\mathrm{Spec}(B)\to\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ you need separability of the residue field extensions (which, because they are generic points, is just $K/F$).

Comment: Having that $\Omega_{B/A}=0$ the map should be unramified (also etale in this particular case) so in particular unramified at the generic point no?

Comment: To check that $\Omega_{B/A}=0$ one just needs to do that at the closed point where the condition on the maximal ideals and on the residue field should be enough to conclude that the module of differentials is zero.

Comment: Why I'm saying to you is that it sounds like you're saying that the map $f:\mathrm{Spec}(B)\to\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is unramified if $\mathfrak{m}B=\mathfrak{n}$ and $A/\mathfrak{m}\to B/\mathfrak{n}$ is an isomorphism. But, this is not true. Presumably you want to use the criterion "a map $X\to Y$ is etale if it's flat and unramified, and its urnamified if for all $x\in X$ with image $y\in Y$ we have that $\mathfrak{m}_y\mathcal{O}_{X,x}=\mathfrak{m}_x$ and $k(x)/k(y)$ is a separable extension" But, you have only checked this at the closed point of $\mathrm{Spec}(B)$, not the generic point.

Comment: To check that $\Omega^1_{B/A}$ is what on the closed point?

Comment: To check that the module vanishes. I edited

Comment: OK, did you read my long comment (like two comments ago)? Does that spark anything for you?

Comment: I read it. Probably I'm missing something stupid but my problem is the following: the map is unramified iff $\Omega_{B/A}=0$ iff it happens what you've written above. One also has a local statement: a map is unramified at $\mathfrak{n}$ iff $\Omega_{B/A,\mathfrak{n}}=0$ iff $\mathfrak{m}B=\mathfrak{n}$ and the  extension of residue fields is separable which here is trivially the case. But $\Omega_{B/A,\mathfrak{n}}=0 $ iff $\Omega_{B/A}=0$ because $B$ is local.

Comment: What is the example in your mind which gives non-trivial $\Omega_{K/F}$ with $\Omega_{B/A} = 0$?

Comment: I've got no precise example in mind but I think it's perfectly reasonable that one could get $K \subseteq F$ not separable

Comment: @TommasoScognamiglio I thought about this, and I actually think that it *is* true. Namely, the etale locus of $\mathrm{Spec}(B)\to\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is open. Since it contains the closed point, it's everything. In some sense, now that I think about (I really actually never thought about this) if your residue field is separable you should be separable. As an intuition, having inseparability largely comes from having $p^\text{th}$ roots and if $T^p-\alpha=0$ has some solution (which up to replacing $\alpha$ by its inverse, you can assume that $\alpha$ is in $\mathcal{O}_K$) then

Comment: this solution must be integral. You can then reduce modulo $p$ to get inseparability in the residue field.

Comment: It still seems strange to me . Also because this seems true for all local rings and not just DVRs which seems pretty general.

Comment: @TommasoScognamiglio, please could you explain why the map you described in the first two lines of your post is unramified. A reference would be great. Thank you!

Comment: @TommasoScognamiglio, also, could we weaken the condition that $B$ is regular to the condition that $B$ is Cohen-Macaulay? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claim: If $A\subset B$ is an inclusion of domains with $Frac(A)=F$ and $Frac(B)=K$ and $\Omega_{B/A}=0$, then $\Omega_{K/F}=0$ as well.

Proof: We use [Stacks 00RT](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00RT):

> Let $\phi: A\to B$ be a ring map.
>
> 1. If $S\subset A$ is a multiplcative subset mapping to invertible elements of $B$, then $\Omega_{B/A}=\Omega_{B/S^{-1}A}$.
> 2. If $S\subset B$ is a multiplcative subset, then $S^{-1}\Omega_{B/A}=\Omega_{S^{-1}B/A}$.

First, letting $S=B\setminus 0$, we see that $$\Omega_{K/A}=\Omega_{S^{-1}B/A}=S^{-1}\Omega_{B/A}=S^{-1}0=0$$ by (2). But then with $S^{-1}=A\setminus 0$ and considering the composite $A\to B\to K$ we have $$\Omega_{K/F}=\Omega_{K/S^{-1}A}=\Omega_{K/A}$$ by (1). So this module $\Omega_{K/F}$ is in fact zero. $\blacksquare$

This applies to your situation and shows your (un)desired result. I think Alex Youcis' interpetation in the comments is a good one: the unramified locus of a morphism is open, and the only open subset of the spectrum of a regular local ring which contains the closed point is the whole spectrum. So if you have that your map is unramified at the closed point, it must be unramified at all points of the spectrum.